# How to customize the MediaManager Notification Control

Tags: xamarin.forms

The Notification UI is displaying quite alright when the audio is playing but I need some little changes on how to customize the Notification UI. The main things that I want is to change the Notification area with background colors and Image.

Some one should please help me for that.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by “media notification”?

Comment: Thank you Sir. I have made some correction in respect of my above question.

Comment: Can you provide more details about `Notification area` ? Thanks.

Comment: I'm new in MediaManager Notification UI, that is why I'm asking on how to set the Notification area background colors and Image

Comment: This article might be helpful for you. Here is the website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications